# Create image viewer in ajax or flash?

Tags: ajax, flash

I've been trying to do more Web development work recently (I currently do other tech stuff, but have some experience with Java, C++, VB, Python, and PHP) and I was asked to create a basic Web site with an image viewer. The site is for an artist and she wants the viewer so users can see thumbnails of her paintings and click them to see a large version.

There are a bunch of existing programs out there (for example, simpleviewer)--most seem to be Flash-based. I want to create my own for various reasons, not least of which is to learn about how to do it. Can anyone give me suggestions/opinions as to what technology to use and how to proceed? Not detailed steps, just pointers in the right direction. (For example, are there existing scripts I could find on the net and then tinker with/modify?) I'm already doing research to figure this out, but advice from savvy programmers will save me some time.

I don't know much about Flash or Ajax, but am willing to learn either (and would eventually like to learn both). I won't be shelling out $700 for Flash Pro right now, so I would need to use something like FlashDevelop if I go that route. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You'll want jQuery. [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com/)
2. Jquery has *tons* of useful plugins: [jquery plugins page](http://plugins.jquery.com/)
3. Start searching! [Here's a good one i found searching for "image galley"](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/advanced.html)
4. Enjoy. Jquery is your friend. Of course this post is biased. So, to give credits to others, you can also look into [mootools](http://mootools.net/), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), [scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/), etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to go down the flash root definitely look at http://slideshowpro.net/ (you don't need the Flash IDE to customise it - all done via XML settings)

An alternative is via JavaScript. A couple of cool scripts to look at are:

- http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/
- http://fancy.klade.lv/

Answer (score 0):

You can scan the images, base64 encode them into a database, then use an < img > tag on your site to point to a PHP page that base64 decodes the images.  No real way to watermark them though you could do that before the you load them using GIMP or some similar tool.